# Python WebApp Facing Running Problems In Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

I'm a newbie and learning Heroku systems. I want to run this [CMS](https://cms-dev.github.io/) on Heroku. I ran it many times on my machine and on others' servers. But I don't have servers all the time. I want to make it on Heroku for contestants.

As always I tried to follow the [docs](https://cms.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4/) of this app. The requirements and setup part runs fine. But the database creation and other parts I couldn't cope up with. As a result, it shows an application error. The app also uses Postgres. But the commands given for ubuntu, I don't know how I can make them in Heroku.

If it sounds stupid question please pardon me. If I have to learn about something please give me some resources to learn.

Or It it is not possible to run this app with heroku, is there any SSH tunelling trick to just make the contestant part online with heroku Or is there any way to just tunnel my localhost to heroku web app domain? Thank You Very Much.

Comment: this is more readable, yes :)